How to remove the dot element from the legend ggplot?
The plot were created as below:
library(forcats)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12),
                   mean=c(80,80,53,53,46,46,42,42,37,37,33,33,
                          28,28,22,22,20,20,17,17,10,10,8,8),
                   type=rep(c("dead","survived"),12),
                   value=c(46,130,220,980,20,840,13,452,8,350,5,69,
                           4,536,16,141,0,55,38,168,12,95,42,170))

mydata%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(id),
             y=value, fill=factor(type,levels=c("dead","survived"))))+
  geom_bar(position=position_stack(),stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(data=subset(mydata,value != 0),
            aes(label = value), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=4) +
  geom_line(color='grey30', linewidth=0.5, aes(x = id, y = mean*30, group=1)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=mean*30)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = mean,y=mean*30+60),size=3.5) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90,0.85)) +
  labs(x="Site ID",y="",fill="Num of pts") +  
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq (0, 1200, 60), name="num of pts",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1/30, name="mean events",breaks = seq (0, 90, 10))
  )


As you can see, there are black dots in the middle of the green and red squares in the legend. So how to remove it?

Two potential options are to include show.legend = FALSE in your geom_point(), or to specify the key_glyph you want to use in each geom (more details: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html), i.e.
library(tidyverse)

mydata<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12),
                   mean=c(80,80,53,53,46,46,42,42,37,37,33,33,
                          28,28,22,22,20,20,17,17,10,10,8,8),
                   type=rep(c("dead","survived"),12),
                   value=c(46,130,220,980,20,840,13,452,8,350,5,69,
                           4,536,16,141,0,55,38,168,12,95,42,170))

mydata%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(id),
             y=value, fill=factor(type,levels=c("dead","survived"))))+
  geom_bar(position=position_stack(),stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(data=subset(mydata,value != 0),
            aes(label = value), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=4) +
  geom_line(color='grey30', linewidth=0.5, aes(x = id, y = mean*30, group=1)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=mean*30), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = mean,y=mean*30+60),size=3.5) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90,0.85)) +
  labs(x="Site ID",y="",fill="Num of pts") +  
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq (0, 1200, 60), name="num of pts",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1/30, name="mean events",
                        breaks = seq(0, 90, 10)))
#> Warning: A numeric `legend.position` argument in `theme()` was deprecated in ggplot2
#> 3.5.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `legend.position.inside` argument of `theme()` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.



mydata%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(id),
             y=value, fill=factor(type,levels=c("dead","survived"))))+
  geom_bar(position=position_stack(),stat="identity", key_glyph = "rect") + 
  geom_text(data=subset(mydata,value != 0),
            aes(label = value), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=4) +
  geom_line(color='grey30', linewidth=0.5, aes(x = id, y = mean*30, group=1),
            key_glyph = "rect") +
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=mean*30),
             key_glyph = "rect") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = mean,y=mean*30+60),size=3.5) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90,0.85)) +
  labs(x="Site ID",y="",fill="Num of pts") +  
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq (0, 1200, 60), name="num of pts",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1/30, name="mean events",
                        breaks = seq(0, 90, 10)))


Created on 2024-06-12 with reprex v2.1.0
